# "Python-Eggs is writable by group/others" Error in Windows 7

Tags: python, trac, bitnami

I installed trac using BitNami the other day and after restarting my computer I'm not able to get it running as a service today.  I see in the error log this error

> [Fri Dec 02 08:52:40.565865 2016] [:error] [pid 4052:tid 968] C:\Bitnami\trac-1.0.13-0\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-7.0-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py:1045: UserWarning: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).

Everyone's suggestion is to move the folder path PYTHON_EGG_CACHE to the C:\egg folder or to suppress the warning at the command line.

I've already set the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE for the system, I set it in trac's setenv.bat file, and in the trac.wsgi file but it's not picking up on the changes when I try to start the service.

Alternately I can't change the permissions on the folder in Roaming using chmod like in Linux, and I can't remove any more permissions on the folder in Roaming (myself, Administrators, System)  as Corporate IT doesn't allow for Administrators to be removed and this isn't an unreasonable policy.

Comment: Have you installed some packages without using the `use_trac.exe` console?

Comment: Apparently the error was a red-herring, like 10 minutes ago I found out that there was another service running on the 8080 port that I had setup trac on and that was causing the trouble.  But to answer your question, no I didn't add extra packages.

Comment: Interesting, nice to hear you've found the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was another service running on the 8080 port that I had setup trac on and that was causing the trouble.  The error in the logs was not pointing to that as being the issue however.